# how to create different versions of a service using angularjs providers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

I have a function called itemService.. gets item from shoppingList controller and push it into items array then return this array back.

now i need to create 2 shoppingLists so using .factory i manged to make both controllers get different version of the service doing this code when i push an item through first controller the array for second controller won't get this item they are spattered 
now how can i do the same using .provider

```
function itemService (limit){
    let share = this;
    share.items=[];
    share.additem=function(N,Q){
        if(limit===undefined || limit>=share.items.length+1){
            let item={N,Q};
            share.items.push(item);
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("limit reached !")
        }  
    }
    share.getItems=function(){
        return share.items;
    }
}

function itemServiceFactory(){
    let factory = function(limit){
        return new itemService (limit);
    };
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Providers, Factories, and Services are singletons. The $get function is only invoked once during the life of an app.

Comment: maybe i couldn't ask my question in good way plz check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory, provider, service, and even value and constant are versions of the same thing. You can dissect the more general provider into all of them. Like so:<sup>[1](http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2015/11/the-difference-between-service-provider-and-factory-in-angularjs/)</sup>

[image]

> From version #1 of question:
>
> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> function itemServiceProvider(){
>     let provider=this;
>     provider.defaults={limit:10};
>     // now i need to make 2 separated version of the service
>     provider.$get = function(){
>         return new itemService (provider.defaults.limit);
>     };
> }
> ```

To convert your factory to a provider:

```
app.provider("MyProvider", function() {
    let provider=this;
    provider.defaults={limit:10};
    provider.$get = function() {
        return function(){
            return new itemService (provider.defaults.limit);
        };
    };
    return provider;
});
```

Usage:

```
app.controller("cntl", function(MyProvider) {
     var service1 = MyProvider();
     var service2 = MyProvider();
})
```

Providers, Factories, and Services are singletons. The $get function is only invoked once during the life of an app. The `provider.$get` function needs to returns a *function* which constructs new services.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15666048/5535245)
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805462/5535245)